# Somebody know how I can do this: 3 oblique divs inside another div? Thank you

Tags: html, css

[image: 3 obliques divs inside another div]

I need 3 oblique divs inside another div, such as in the picture. Somebody help me?

Comment: I'm certain that there will be a way, but may I ask why?  It seems like an icon would be a neat way to do this without anything clever.  The _why_ may be important in this case

Comment: Thanks, I tried but couldn't. I need this such as a traffic light, to change colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is use of 3 internl divs important to you?

```css
.square1,.square2{
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.square1 div{
  width: 142%; /* phytagoras */
  position: relative;
  left: -21%;
  top: -21%;
  height: 47.33%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.square1 div:nth-child(1){
  transform-origin:  50% 150%;
}
.square1 div:nth-child(3){
  transform-origin:  50% -50%;
}
.square2:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 26.333%;
  left: -21%;
  width: 142%;
  height: 47.3%;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
with 3 divs:
<div class="square1">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

without divs:
<div class="square2"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with `transform: rotate()` and `position: absolute`. For moving the divs to the center you could use `transform: translate()`.

**Working example:**

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -25%);
}

#container div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```